# .html() not returning modified version of cloned DOM subtree

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at the simple little `div` containing a radio-button `input`. Then look at the Javascript that grabs the `div` and clones it with `.clone()`, saving it to variable `y`, and then finds the `input` elements within it, and then iterates over them in order to modify them -- it's supposed to uncheck the radio button -- but when I print the `div` with `.html()`, the radio button is still checked! But why? And how do I get `.html()` to return the unchecked version?

```js
var y = $('div.foo').clone();
console.log(y.html());
y.find('input').each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).prop('checked', false); // turn off the radio button
});
console.log(y.html());
//$('input[name=x_0]').prop('checked', false); // this will do it
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
    <input type="radio" name="x_0" value="email" checked="checked"> email
</div>
```

Comment: You are running up against the difference between attributes and DOM properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html. Depending on the behavior you may need to remove the `checked` attribute while in your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing a property of a dom element doesn't change the HTML - if you update the value of an `input`, it doesn't update the html to say `<input value='whatever'/>`, the HTML stays the same, but a property of the dom element has changed.  If you want to *also* change the html, you have to use `.attr`:

```js
var y = $('div.foo').clone();
console.log(y.html());
y.find('input').each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).prop('checked', false)
    $(el).attr('checked', null); // turn off the radio button
});
console.log(y.html());
//$('input[name=x_0]').prop('checked', false); // this will do it
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">
    <input type="radio" name="x_0" value="email" checked="checked"> email
</div>
```

Comment: you are right - `.attr` worked! Is it really supposed to be set to `null` (because `false` worked for me). Also, I chose to only talk about `input[type=radio]` but I was also having the same problem with `input[type=text]` because I was using `$(el).val('');` whereas I have now succeeded with `$(el).attr('value', '');` -- would you concur that that is the same issue, or a different one?

Comment: thats the same issue.  it probably doesn't make a difference whether you set it to false or null

Comment: hmm, it might actually have to be `null`. see http://api.jquery.com/attr/ and search for "null"... it says that in `.attr( attributeName, value )` **value** can take on one of three types: "String or Number or Null", and if set to `null`, the specified attribute will be removed (as in `.removeAttr()`).

Comment: this is insane / maddening / crazy making

Comment: Here is the line in jQuery's source code that checks whether `value` is `null`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/attr.js#L50